# Domain model mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, automapper, valueinjecter

I have domain model and data model:

- Domain model (DoM) is designed for business layers to simplify the operations.
- Data model (DaM) is automatically generated from the data base using entity framework.

I would like to map DoM <> DaM in both directions. I have tried Automapper, but I am having one big issue with it, say DaM data model has an entity Car, which is a direct translation of the database table

```
Car
{
   Type {get; set;}
   MaxSpeed {get; set;}
}
```

Domain model DoM has the following structure:

```
Car
{
   MaxSpeed {get; set;}
}

SportsCar : Car
{
}

F1 : SportsCar 
{
}
```

And the mapping should be:

```
if (DaM.Car(car).Type == Type.SportsCar)
   DaM.Car.MaxSpeed > 350 ? map DaM.car to DoM.F1 : map DaM.car to DoM.SportsCar
```

**What is the best way/tool to archive that?**

**How I can do it with automapper or valueinject?**

Comment: You can't map to a particular type based on the value of a property and you should not model your data like that. Changing the value of a property should not change an objects type.

Comment: Thanks for your input, we have considered several designs, we would really like to have a class hierarchy in code and a normalized sql data schema. Simplest way to do what we want in sql is a type column (it is in fact way more complicated than one column, it is a combination of columns + what type of references object has). The mapping is static, meaning once the data were mapped from DaM to DoM they living on their own till they are mapped back which is simple or thrown away and mapped new.

Comment: You probably want to use Table Per Hierarchy inheritance in EF, which uses a discriminator column/property to pick the correct derived type. You will then have an appropriate EF model for each domain model to map back and forth. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618292.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Table Per Hierarchy mappings using Entity Framework? Using the Type property on Car as the discriminator, you'd be able to add SportsCar and F1 entities to the data model and Entity Framework would retrieve them direct from the database. You could then use AutoMapper if you really want to have separate SportsCar and F1 classes in your domain model.

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

valueinjecter by default will match all properties of same name and type from source to target regardless of types
so it would be something like this:

```
a.InjectFrom(b);
```

note a and b already exist, you create them in advance

you can see valueinjecter being used with EF in mvc project here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com